# C# breaking out of XML reading function if XML file is no longer available

Tags: c#, xml, network-programming

I have a function that reads an XML page from a device attached to the network. The page is reached via url. The problem I'm having is that if I remove the device from the network while the function is parsing the XML page, the code freezes forever. How can I break out of the function if this happens? This is the code (the function returns a list of tags `<example>`):

```
public static List<string> GetTags(string xmlLocation) {    //xmlLocation = http://192.x.x.x/xmlpage
    List<string> dataList = new List<string>();                                             
    XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(xmlLocation);                                                                                                  
    while (reader.Read())                                                                   
    {
        switch (reader.NodeType)
        {
            case XmlNodeType.Element:                                                       
                dataList.Add(lastHeader);                                                    
                break;                                                                                                                                            
        }
    }
    reader.Dispose();
    return dataList;
}
```

Comment: You are reading a stream that uses TCP for the transport layer.  TCP will stay open until the socket connection completes.  You can use a keep alive to determine if connection breaks.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.servicepoint.settcpkeepalive?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: You really should have the `reader` in a `using` so that it will be disposed even if an exception occurs.

Comment: Is the xml reasonably small to first transfer it completely, then parse, instead of stream-parsing it?

Comment: @Fildor yes, it's less than 100 lines. It could grow but I imagine it would never be longer than 200 max. How could I transfer it?

Comment: Well, you can http/Get. The comment suggests you are already using http.