# C# hanging code when XML from URL is interrupted

Tags: c#, xml, network-programming

I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63671605/c-sharp-breaking-out-of-xml-reading-function-if-xml-file-is-no-longer-available) yesterday.

Essentially, I'm trying to parse an XML from a URL but my code hangs forever if the connection is lost when attempting to read the XML.

I am still having the same problem, however I changed the code in a way I thought would prevent the program from freezing if the connection to the URL was interrupted. Could someone please explain why my solution didn't work and how I can fix it? Thanks!

Here are the two functions I am using. `CanReach` just checks the connection to make sure the URL is there, and `GetTags` gets all the parent tags of the XML file. I want it to break if the connection is interrupted. I tried to do this by loading the xml file instead of parsing it right from the URL and using `try` and `catch` to catch the error. `xmlLocation` is the URL.

```
public static bool CanReach(string xmlLocation)
{
    WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(xmlLocation);                                    
    request.Timeout = 1000;
    try                                                                                     
    {
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        response.Dispose();                                                                 
        request.Abort();                                                                    
        return true;                                                                        
    }
    catch (System.Net.WebException)                                                          
    {
        request.Abort();                                                                    
        return false;                                                                       
    }
}

public static List<string> GetTopTags(string xmlLocation)
{
    bool canBeReached = CanReach(xmlLocation);
    if (canBeReached)
    {
        try
        {
            XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
            xmlDoc.Load(xmlLocation);                                 
            XmlReader reader = new XmlNodeReader(xmlDoc);
            List<string> dataList = new List<string>();            
            while (reader.Read())                                                                   
            {
                switch (reader.NodeType)
                {
                    case XmlNodeType.Text:                                                          
                        dataList.Add(reader.Name);                                                   
                        break;                                                                      
                }
            }
            reader.Dispose();
            return topTags;                                                                       
        }
        catch
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }
    
}
```

Comment: The reader.Read() is a blocking method so if you hang in the middle of a xml you are going to hang.  You have to find out why the connection is being lost.  There are a few things you can try.  I would start with cmd.exe  >Ping -t -l 65500 IP which will continuously perform ping with large packets so you can see if there are error occurring.

Comment: I can't control the connection being lost, that's why I'm trying to break when it's lost. I also thought that using `xmlDoc.Load` would get me around this because, I thought, it would cache the XML file so I would only need to use HTTP in order to retrieve the XML file, and then read it regardless the connection was lost or not.

Comment: If a connection is being dropped, you must find the source and fix provided it is bad hardware.

Comment: Again, I don't (and can't) control when the connection drops. It could be for various reasons (the most likely is the device goes offline). I need the code to break and continue because it has to get information from multiple devices.

Comment: How often does the problem occur?  It sounds like the problem occurs frequently.  You can always put the code in a backgroundworker and run the worker asynchronously so when it hang other backgroundworkers can continue.  But if it is occurring frequently I would investigate why.

Comment: This problem occurs rarely, however if it does I need a way to continue. My code reads XML data from devices on the network, if it happens that I'm reading the XML from the device when the firmware is being changed, or it's taken off the network, then my code freezes. I still need to continue if that happens.

Answer (score 0):

We can start of another thread that is reading the XML file and the current method can continuously check whether connection is alive or not. If the we can not reach the URL anymore, we can cancel the operation and return null. If the read operation is finished, `isFinished` flag is set and we can return `returnValue`.

Try this:

```
public static List<string> GetTopTags(string xmlLocation)
{
    bool canBeReached = CanReach(xmlLocation);

    if (!canBeReached)
        return null;

    List<string> returnValue = null;
    CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
    bool isFinished = false;

    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        try
        {
            var xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
            xmlDoc.Load(xmlLocation);
            using var reader = new XmlNodeReader(xmlDoc);
            List<string> dataList = new List<string>();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                switch (reader.NodeType)
                {
                    case XmlNodeType.Text:
                        dataList.Add(reader.Name);
                        break;
                }
            }

            if (reader.ReadState == ReadState.Error)
                returnValue = null;
            else
                returnValue = topTags;
        }
        catch
        {
            returnValue = null;
        }

        isFinished = true;
    }, cts.Token, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning, TaskScheduler.Default);

    while (!isFinished)
        if (!CanReach(xmlLocation))
            cts.Cancel();

    return returnValue;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will implement it and test

Answer (score 0):

I'm not wild about that `XmlDocument.Load()` and passing it a URL. You're handing over too much control and it's making it hard for you to debug. I would separate out the networking and the XML reading. With the networking separated out, you eliminate the need for your `CanReach()` function. Anything network related needs to be ran in a separate thread. Based on your source, something like the following is what I might start with.

```
public static async Task<List<string>> GetTopTags(string xmlLocation)
{
    string xmlText = null;

    try
    {
        // You are free to use WebRequest here, I've used WebClient for simplicity.
        using (var webClient = new WebClient())
        {
            xmlText = await webClient.DownloadStringTaskAsync(xmlLocation);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        // Handle network related issues.
    }

    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(xmlText))
    {
        // We weren't able to download the XML, or the downloaded XML is not valid,
        // "CanReach()" is false.
        return null;
    }

    // We downloaded the XML successfully if you get here, now just read it.

    XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
    xmlDoc.Load(new StringReader(xmlText));

    using (XmlReader reader = new XmlNodeReader(xmlDoc))
    {
        List<string> dataList = new List<string>();

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            switch (reader.NodeType)
            {
                case XmlNodeType.Text:
                    dataList.Add(reader.Name);
                    break;
            }
        }

        return dataList;
    }
}
```